# What's the ports tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Please add missing documentation of the [ports tag](https://superuser.com/tags/ports/info). It might be interpreted as related to multiple network ports, FreeBSD ports or else.

Comment: Its a bad tag then. freebsd ports *should* be its own tag, and so on. I think its a wider issue than just tag wiki-ing. We need some retagging and such too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these can be divided into [tcpip-ports](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tcpip-ports), [bsd-ports](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsd-ports), and maybe [physical-ports](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/physical-ports), though that doesn't seem like a terribly useful tag to me (example question is [What does COM Stand for in terms of Serial Ports](https://superuser.com/questions/435213/what-does-com-stand-for-in-terms-of-serial-ports)).

Any objections or improvements?  If not, I can go through and retag for the tcpip/bsd distinction, and remove the physical ports.